# Чат-Бот VK C#, парсинг страницы

Tags: c#, вконтакте, бот

Привет, задача такая. Добавляю бота в конференцию и пишу. 
"Бот, погода"
Он мне выводит цифру с сайта(на самом деле другая инфа нужна, но неважно)
Ничего более, только одна команда и одна цифра

Что мне для этого изучить?
Я уже создал прилоение в вк, Настроил oauth, корректно возвращает access token.
Но дальше не знаю, как быть.

Но в идеале не хотелось бы не использовать бота, а использовать мой аккаунт. То есть мне пишут "Михаил, погода" и я автоматом выдаю погоду. Так возможно?

Comment: Возможно. Разрабатываете искусственный интеллект и подключаете, делов-то!

Comment: Возможно. Всего-то стоит разобраться с VK API и любым серверным языком программирования.

Comment: Не обязательно серверный, можно и клиента написать и в автозагрузку поставить, если там простенько всё. А по сабжу - идите читайте документацию, примеров везде полно как на шарпе работать в вк, есть даже готовые библиотечки в nuget, за вас тут такие вещи никто не напишет.

Comment: @Сергей за себя я не просил писать, так как это надо мне, и это интересно.

Comment: @terron я просто не совсем понимаю, где это все вертеться будет.
Вот я напишу приложение на C#. На странице приложения не видно, куда его загрузить нужно. Или это должно быть постоянно запущенно на моей машине?

Comment: @AntonSokolovskii "Или это должно быть постоянно запущенно на моей машине?" - второй вариант. Вообще, задача не особо сложная, если все ограничивается заранее оговоренными командами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да Михаил такое возможно.

1 шаг: API работы с погодой

Есть много сервисов работающии с API погодой (парсить html не придеться) есть платные, есть бесплатные. Вот 1 из них https://tech.yandex.ru/weather/

Одной проблемой меньше.

2 шаг: VK API прием сообщения

Если вы собираетесь реализовать бота средствами C# то знайте, сообщения приходят в неправильной кодировке. Вот я раньше писал бота и также задавал вопрос на форуме

[Проблема с кодировкой C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679019/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-c)

С кодировкой разобрались, теперь как принимать сообщения:

```
private string messagesGet(int count, string version)
    {
        string url = ("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get?count=" + count + "&access_token=" + token + "&v=" + version);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var json = client.DownloadString(url);
        return json;
    }
```

Вот функция она вернет вам ответ сервера в формате {respone: бла бла бла}

Это все вам предеться перепарсить.
Для этого рекомендую использовать одинаковую версию при запроссе messagesGet и наисать собственную функцию которая принимала ответ сервера (Json) в String формате и возвращала само сообщение и id пользователя. Для реализации этой функтии понадобиться много строковых массивов и работа с разделением строку на массив. Поэтому прочитайте это.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.100).aspx

Вот моя версия парсинга сообщения, но если вернеться ошибка или сообщение будет содиржать " то бот будет работать  не стабильно, рекомендую не использавать мои наработки :D

```
private string[] messagesGetParse(string json)
    {
        string uid, body;
        string[] massiv = json.Split(':');
        string a = massiv[8];
        string[] arrayA = a.Split('"');
        body = arrayA[1];
        string[] arrayB = massiv[5].Split(',');
        uid = arrayB[0];
        return new string[] { uid, body };
    }
```

3 шаг: VK API отправка сообщения

Тут все такде как и с получением сообщения только метод другой, и парамметры.

Вот мои наработки)))

Это для отправки обычного сообщения

```
private void messagesSend(string user_id, string message)
    {
        string url = ("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=" + 
        user_id + "&message=" + message + "&access_token=" + token);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var json = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

Если же вы хотите отправить стикер то нужно перегрузить этот метод

http://mycsharp.ru/post/37/2014_02_04_peregruzka_metodov_v_si-sharp.html

Интересная статья про перегрузку)

Вот как это сделал я:

```
private void messagesSend(string user_id, int sticker_id)
    {
        string url = ("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=" + 
        user_id + "&sticker_id=" + sticker_id + "&access_token=" + token);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var json = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

Вот и всё осталось найти хороший сервис для работы с погодой средствами API.

Удачи, надеюсь что я писал это все не зря.

Обьяснял подробно, ну если новички читать будут)

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ! Пару замечаний: разбирать JSON вручную нет надобности — нужно подходящим образом сделать десериализацию (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data). Сообщение перед передачей надо кодировать процентами или вообще воспользоваться специальным построителем URL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/txt7706a.aspx).

Comment: Стоит отметить, что для C# существуют уже готовые библиотеки для взаимодействия с ВК (https://github.com/nolka/vkdotnet, как пример)