# Проблема с кодировкой C#

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Я работаю с *VK API*. При запросах с браузера все работает стабильно, но при запросах из моей программы английские символы возвращаются правильно, а русские - нет. Погуглив я понял, что проблема в кодировке `"РЎРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёРµ"`. Но я не смог найти ни одного понятного мне примера. Код работает, но не так как нужно((([image: То что он вывел, и то что должно получиться]

**Помогите переконвертировать из кодировки `cp1361` в `UTF8`**

Comment: Мне кажется, это CP1251.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myStringInCP1361);
myStringInUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь WebClient(), то просто укажи кодировку:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```